# need to read CSV with carriage returns as "data" using Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file that has the following possible formats:

```
Parameter, value1, value2, value3/r/n

Parameter, value1/r/n
value2/r/n
value3/r/n

Parameter,/r/n
/r/n
/r/n
```

I have no problems dealing with the first two cases, but the last case is giving me a hard time. I would like to maintain the number of carriage returns and translate that into blank items in a dictionary:

```
{'parameter': ['','','']}
```

The code I created so far:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data_file = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
    data_file_iter = iter(data_file)
    for i,row in enumerate(data_file_iter):
       if len(row) == len(results['Results Table 1']):
           results[row[0]]=row[1:]
               else:
                   results[row[0]]=row[1:]
                   while len(results[row[0]]) < len(results['Results Table 1']):
                       results[row[0]].extend(next(data_file_iter,''))
```

And a snippet of the csv.reader output:

```
[['Results Table 1', '1', '2', '3'], ['Operator', 'name1'], ['name1'], ['name1'], ['Test Date', '2/26/2020'], ['2/26/2020'], ['2/26/2020'], ['Test Temperature', '70'], ['70'], ['70'], ['Relative Humidity (%)', '25.00'], ['25.00'], ['25.00'], ['Test Pressure', 'Ambient'], ['Ambient'], ['Ambient'], ['Comments', ''], [], [], ['Failure Location', 'Advancing'], ['Advancing'], ['Advancing'], ['Initial Thickness (in)', '0.1910'], ['0.1900', '0.1910'], ['Initial Width (in)', '1.0060', '1.0070', '1.0010'], ['First Initial Marks (in) (in)', '0.0000'], ['0.0000'], ['0.0000'], ['First Final Marks (in) (in)', '0.0000'], ['0.0000'], ['0.0000'], ['Second Initial Marks (in) (in)', '0.0000'], ['0.0000'], ['0.0000'], ['Second Final Marks (in) (in)', '0.0000'], ['0.0000'], ['0.0000'], ['Tensile stress at Maximum Load (ksi)', '47.86', '46.04', '45.49'], ['Force at Maximum Load (kip)', '9.20', '8.81', '8.70'], [' 0.2 % Offset Yield Stress (ksi)', '28.12', '-----'], ['-----'], ["Young's Modulus (Msi)", '10.62', '121.09', '145.14'], ['Tensile stress at 100% of Break (Tensile extension) (ksi)', '26.22', '34.55', '43.67'], ['Force at 100% of Break (Tensile extension) (kip)', '5.04', '6.61', '8.35']]
```

Notice that some of the comments are empty lists, that is not always the case. I am not married to using csv.reader, but would prefer it.

Thank you for any and all help that is provided.

Comment: So essentially each csv row is 4 items? a parameter and then 3 fields? regardless of the lines they are on?

Comment: The rows are of arbitrary length, but should all be the same length.

Comment: WWould you know the length of the rows before parsing the file? or will the first row at least be in the single row format to allow determining of the field length for all remaining ros?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I can base the length off of the first row (Results Table 1,...,...), at least, I haven't had any cases where that first row was separated. Lets just assume that we can get the length from the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming based on your description that every row should be 4 fields wide. You could just replace all the new lines with commas then use range to generate the index number of every 4th field. You can then use that to get the parameter name and put the next 3 fields in a list. The below is just a quick example of how you could do this. But of course to be more clean and not worry about nested commas etc you could still use CSV reader to parse the data and then iterate it like this.

This solution does assume that you can read the entire file into memory. If you are talking about significantly large files then let me know as a different solution would be needed to read the file line by line

```py
# Read the entire file into memory (hoping these are not large files :D)
with open("Data.csv") as my_csv_file:
    data = my_csv_file.read()

# get the index of the first line and collect the data in the first line and split it
# so we can work out the nuber of fields per record as all records will have same num fields
index_of_end_of_first_line = data.find("\n")
num_fields = len(data[:index_of_end_of_first_line].split(','))

# Replace all new lines with commas and start an empty dict
data_fields = data.replace("\n", ",").split(',')
data_dict = {}

#loop over all the fields picking N number of fields at a time based on num_fields value
for index in range(0, len(data_fields), num_fields):
    data_dict[data_fields[index]] = data_fields[index + 1:index + num_fields]
    print(data_fields[index:index + num_fields])
print(data_dict)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['Results Table 1', '1', '2', '3']
['Operator', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3']
['Test Date', '2/26/2020', '2/26/2020', '2/26/2020']
['Test Temperature', '70', '70', '70']
['Relative Humidity (%)', '25.00', '25.00', '25.00']
['Test Pressure', 'Ambient', 'Ambient', 'Ambient']
['Comments', '', '', '']
['Failure Location', 'Advancing', 'Advancing', 'Advancing']
['Tensile stress at Maximum Load (ksi)', '47.86', '46.04', '45.49']
['Force at Maximum Load (kip)', '9.20', '8.81', '8.70']
{'Results Table 1': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Operator': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 'Test Date': ['2/26/2020', '2/26/2020', '2/26/2020'], 'Test Temperature': ['70', '70', '70'], 'Relative Humidity (%)': ['25.00', '25.00', '25.00'], 'Test Pressure': ['Ambient', 'Ambient', 'Ambient'], 'Comments': ['', '', ''], 'Failure Location': ['Advancing', 'Advancing', 'Advancing'], 'Tensile stress at Maximum Load (ksi)': ['47.86', '46.04', '45.49'], 'Force at Maximum Load (kip)': ['9.20', '8.81', '8.70']}
```

Comment: The number of items for each parameter is arbitrary, however all parameters have the same number of items.

I will still need to read the file into the code, this is going to be part of a larger program that will cycle through lots of these programatically.

Comment: based on your comments in the question, i have updated the code to decide the field length from the first line of the data.

Comment: I am not sure how to apply your code to my problem because you don't utilize a csv file. I will edit my post with what the csv reader outputs instead of what the csv file looks like.

Comment: I didnt use CSV reader as you had at the bottom said you were not married to the idea of having to use it. However i did suggest you could still use it to ensure you validate and split nested parenthesis correctly

Comment: sorry, that's not what I meant. I meant, I don't care how the file is read in, but I still need to read it from a file.

Comment: Oh that part can be done easily I will update the code to read it from a file instead of the string. Essentially your just opening the file like before and reading the entire contents of the file into a variable called data and all the rest will work

Comment: Updated now to show reading the contents of the file into a variable called data.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I was missing... I was delimiting the file with csv.reader and trying to re-run it through your code. thank you very much for the help!